# Google Smart lock for the Facebook login

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I am using Google Smart Lock in my application and it's working fine for Google Sign In, but for the Facebook Sign In I can’t find any documentation to save the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
LoginManager.getInstance().apply {
    registerCallback(facebookCallbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> 
        override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
            // Save the credentials on Google Smart Lock
            smartLockClient.save(Credential.Builder(loginResult.accessToken.userId)
                .setAccountType(IdentityProviders.FACEBOOK)
                .build()
            )
        }
        ...
    }
    logInWithReadPermissions(this@LoginActivity, mutableListOf("email", "public_profile"))
}
```

Comment: What about access token expiration?